# Changing file associations in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, files, nautilus

[This blog post](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/change-default-applications-easily-in-gnome/1138) talks about how to change the default application to handle a file type in Nautilus for individual file types (right-click on the file, "open with", and select the new default application), but is there a way to list *all* current associations and configure them in one go, similar to the Windows "folder options | file types" tab?  There seem to be a bunch of default associations that I want to change (all various image files are being opened in IceWeasel instead of the image viewer), and I don't want to have to change them one-by-one in the file manager.  If there's no GUI for doing this, then where does Nautilus store its file associations?  Can I edit them with a text editor?

Answer (score 13):

On my system (Debian Jessie) I found all the normal methods of specifying a default application wouldn't override the one hiding in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Thunar insisted on opening a particular file with gedit even after I told it to make the correct application the default. When I removed the setting from `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, it started working properly again.

Answer (score 8):

All of your file associations are stored in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Some of them are not in your personal `mimeapps.list` file. There's a system wide file with all the default associations in `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and/or in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

<strike>For more info check out [Specifications/mime-actions-spec](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec)</strike>

Edit: 
In Fedora 14 I have these settings files:

```
/var/lib/gdm/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
/usr/local/share/applications/defaults.list
$HOME/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little in that I do indeed have a `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` with a few added associations, however I do not have any `.list` files in `/usr/share/applications/` and yet there are evidently a bunch of other default associations stored somewhere.  Do you know where else they could be stored?

Comment: More strangeness.  I've looked through all the `defaults.list` and `mimeapps.list` files on the system, and in two of them, JPEG images are actually configured to run with `eog.desktop` which should open them in the image viewer and not Iceweasel, and yet Nautilus still opens JPEG images in Iceweasel.  How could it be getting this file association?

Comment: That is strange. I have this: `$ cat ./.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list | grep jpeg
image/jpeg=gthumb.desktop;gnome-eog.desktop;`

Comment: your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

The file you need to edit is /etc/gnome/defaults.list.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. That file exists, but it applies to all users. You can change the associations in the GNOEe GUI and these changes end up in ~/.config/mimeapps.list so that's what I edit.